# Notebook gets stuck during shutdown

Tags: opensuse, shutdown, kernel-panic

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad with the latest openSUSE Tumbleweed installed (kernel 5.11.6-1-default). Very often when I shutdown this notebook it gets stuck and I see a black screen with a flashing CapsLock, which is very similar to kernel panic. The latest message I see before the screen goes black is the error:

```
"rmi4_physical rmi4-00: Failed to read irqs, code=-6"
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Update1**: It's weird that the reboot goes well. I see the same message, but the notebook reboots without problems.

**Update2**: The only difference between reboot and shutdown is that on reboot I get an additional message:

```
watchdog: watchdog0: watchdog did not stop
```

**Update 3**: I still have this problem on openSUSE Tumbleweed with kernel 5.12.0. Also I just installed Fedora 34 with kernel 5.11.17 and got the same issue. I guess it's definitely a kernel issue.

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Comment: Are you running any java applications at shutdown? rmi usually implies java's "remote method invocation."

Comment: @NasirRiley I haven't found any suspicious messages in the logs

Comment: @CinaedSimson I haven't launched any Java applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue also on Ubuntu 21.04 with kernel 5.11.0-17. Currently I'm on openSUSE Tumbleweed with kernel 5.12.2-1 and this issue is gone. So it was definitely a kernel issue.